# Xslt size of token array (tokenize, number of tokens)

Tags: html, arrays, list, xslt, functional-programming

Is there a way to getting the size of a token array after having run `tokenize($text, '\s+')`? Without running a loop.

I miss Java in these cases where I can just run `list.size()`.

Cheers

Answer

```
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize($text, '\s+')"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="count($tokens)"></xsl:value-of>
```

Comment: You get a sequence of string values returned from `tokenize`, not an array, and as with all sequences in XSLT/XPath 2.0 or later you can use the `count` function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-count) to find the number of items in the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `count()` around tokenize. In your case `count(tokenize($text, '\s+'))`

Comment: I would have to tokenize two times in this case. First to count and second to get the tokens in a variable.

Comment: Doh! I can just pass the variable into the count function. Overlook my comment above.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you are using XSLT and wants to keep count of token and its tokens in variables, you need to create two variables.